# All css style rules are stripped from one div element but no other elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a header for a website where the title of the site is displayed over an image. I set it up to use a div class element with a background image. However, I can't figure out why the background image in this div class element I created is not displaying.

After inspection I've found out that the css style rules associated with the div class element are being stripped of the element when I render it (in Firefox and Chrome, haven't tried IE).

I have the css setup like this:

```
.text-over-image {
   width: 960px;
   height: 100px;
   background-image: url("http://www.lupenet.org/wp-content/themes/Lupenet/images/header.jpg");
   margin-left: auto ;
   margin-right: auto ;
}

h8 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 20px; 
   left: 400px; 
   width: 960px;
}

h8 span { 
   color: black; 
   font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
   letter-spacing: -1px;  
   padding: 10px; 
}

h8 span.spacer1 {
   padding:0 5px;
}
```

And the html looks like this:

```
<div class="text-over-image;" >
   <h8><span style="position:absolute;">La Unión Del Pueblo Entero<span class='spacer1'></span>
   <br><span class='spacer1'></span>"Celebrando el Pasado y Viendo Hacia el Futuro"</span></h8>
</div>
```

After realizing there was a problem, I set the height and width attributes of the element `.text-over-image` in case the div was just being rendered too small to view the image, but the background image still didn't display. When I inspected the element using firebug, I found out the div element `.text-over-image` does not show any background image attribution at all. In fact, all css style rules are stripped from that div element.

I even tried copying the css and html of another website that does exactly what I'm trying to do, but when I do it, the same thing happens (style rules are stripped from that div element). However, the css style rules are not stripped from the other elements.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` from your class:

```
<div class="text-over-image;">
```

It should be just `<div class="text-over-image">`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t2r7Y/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I read your css and after that I just came to this point! There is no legal `h8` element in HTML.

So I guess the issue is the usage of h8, try replacing it with h6.

Comment: even with an invalid `h` tag, the image should still appear. i think the error was the `;` in the tag as described below