# CSS being stripped from a single div element in outlook online

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I am trying to create an email that is properly visible in both the online version of outlook and gmail. I seem to have it working fine in gmail but have encountered a weird issue when it comes to outlook. I have two identical  elements with an image inside. When I view the first one in outlook it strips the entire element of the inline style properties. It then works perfectly fine on the second  with identical code. (see screenshot) I know there are weird inconsistencies between email clients but I am not sure what is going on here. If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

I looked around and the only person who seemed to have a similar problem to me was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958129/all-css-style-rules-are-stripped-from-one-div-element-but-no-other-elements) but I at least haven't found any stray semicolons like was the issue there.

```html
<table>
  <td align="left">
    <div id="wrapper" style="width: 600px;background-image: linear-gradient(#15dbff, #6aff90);margin-top: 0px;position: absolute;top: 0px;">
      <table height="20px" width="600px">
        <tr height="20px" width="600px"></tr>
      </table>
      <div id="heading" style="width: 452px;height: 131px;background-color: white;margin: auto;margin-top: 20px;border-radius: 25px;">
        <img id="headerimg" src="https://kevinuulong.com/images/KLlogocolredcircle.png" style="width: 131px; margin-left: 150px;">
      </div>
      <div id="body" style="width: 392px;background-color: white;margin: auto;margin-top: 20px;border-radius: 25px;padding: 30px;">
        <p id="greeting">Mr. Somebody,</p>
        <p id="mainbody">This is some sample text. It should be using the Montserrat font family. <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;background: linear-gradient(to right, #15dbff, #6aff90);background-repeat: repeat-x;background-size: 100% 2px;background-position: 0 95%;color: #001744;">This</a>          is what a link should look like. Any images should be inside a div like this.
          <div class="bodyimage" style="width: 392px;height: 200px;overflow: hidden;border-radius: 25px;margin-bottom: 10px;"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?colors/392x200"></div>
          <div class="bodyimage" style="width: 392px;height: 200px;overflow: hidden;border-radius: 25px;margin-bottom: 10px;"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?colors/392x200"></div>
        </p>
        <p id="signature">Thanks,<br>Kevin Long</p>
      </div>
      <div id="contact" style="width: 452px;background-color: white;margin: auto;margin-top: 20px;margin-bottom: 20px;border-radius: 25px;">
        <table>
          <th style="width: 50%;"> <img id="contactimg" src="https://kevinuulong.com/images/KLlogocolredcircle.png" style="width: 120px;"></th>
          <th style="width: 50%;"><a href="https://kevinuulong.com" style="text-decoration: none;background: linear-gradient(to right, #15dbff, #6aff90);background-repeat: repeat-x;background-size: 100% 2px;background-position: 0 95%;color: #001744;">kevinuulong.com</a><br><br>
            <a
              id="btn" href="mailto:someone@example.com" style="text-decoration: none;background: #5284ff;background-repeat: repeat-x;background-size: 100% 2px;background-position: 0 95%;color: white;padding-left: 50px;padding-right: 50px;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom: 10px;border-radius: 20px;">Contact Me</a>
          </th>
        </table>
      </div>
      <table height="20px" width="600px">
        <tr height="20px" width="600px"></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </td>
</table>
```

[image: Example of the stripped style tag]

Comment: Can't debug that code unfortunately, your domain can't be reached, so the images aren't loading when testing.
One major thing you should fix in the #body, are the divs nested inside of the p tag. That isn't valid HTML and Litmus is highlighting this as an error.

I can't imagine that is affecting the rendering but just something extra to fix.

Answer (score 1):

The basic requirements for Outlook are, for each image, to have the width and height attributes, i.e.:

```
<img width="392" height="200" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?colors/392x200">
```

Div's don't tend to play well with Outlook; that's why we're still using tables for layout.

If you need the image to be responsive, add this in the style:

```
<img width="392" height="200" style="width:100%;height:auto;max-width:392px" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/?colors/392x200">
```